# Python 3 how to format integer into IPv6 address using f string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, f-string

I am trying to format integers into IPv6 addresses.

IPv6 address here means a string that represents an integer between 0 and 2^128 - 1 (340282366920938463463374607431768211455), formatted into 32 hexadecimal digits, separated by colons (`':'`) into 8 fields of 4 digits each.

Now I know of `str(ipaddress.IPv6Address(n))` and `int(ipaddress.IPv6Address(s))`, but I want to write my own functions in the name of learning, and I have already written them and I am trying to improve them.

I am looking for a way to format integers into IPv6 format using either f-strings or `str.format`, I currently use this one-liner:

```
ipv6 = ':'.join(hex(n).removeprefix('0x').zfill(32)[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 32, 4))
```

And it is slow, because it uses string slicing.

I have already written codes to shorten IPv6 addresses using regexes, and I am looking to replace the above mentioned one-liner using a string format one-liner.

I have already implemented the first part (format an integer into 32 bit hexadecimal with leading zeros and without `'0x'` prefix) using this:

```
"{0:0>32x}".format(n)
```

But I cannot implement the second part, I have Google searched for a way to insert a separator every N characters into strings using Python but most are irrelevant no matter what keywords I use, and I have only seen two relevant methods, one being the method I am using that I came up with by myself, the other is this:

`re.sub('([\da-fA-F]{4})', r'\1:', s, 7)`

But regexes are slow:

```
In [221]: re.sub('([\da-fA-F]{4})', r'\1:', 'c42d7a7d155b93f7658c20c9fea598ff', 7)
Out[221]: 'c42d:7a7d:155b:93f7:658c:20c9:fea5:98ff'

In [222]: s = 'c42d7a7d155b93f7658c20c9fea598ff'

In [223]: %timeit re.sub('([\da-fA-F]{4})', r'\1:', s, 7)
11.6 µs ± 993 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [224]: %timeit ':'.join(s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 32, 4))
2.11 µs ± 23.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

But I have found this keyword: Python f string thousand separator in Google search suggestions and found this syntax: "{:,d}"

```
In [226]: "{:,d}".format(1234567890)
Out[226]: '1,234,567,890'
```

It is pretty close to what I seek, but unfortunately it isn't the method, first it deals with integers (`d`), secondly it inserts a separator every 3 characters instead of 4, and finally it uses a comma instead of a colon, and I can't change that without invalidating the syntax...

So what is the correct f-string syntax to insert a colon every 4 digits while formatting integer to 32 digit hexadecimal string? Preferably without f-string nesting. And I am looking for a one-liner.

By f-string nesting I meaning something like this:

```
f'{f"{n:0>32x}"}'
```

I don't know if that is valid, and I don't like it.

---

Currently I have done this:

```
"{0:0>32_x}".format(n)
```

```
In [248]: "{0:0>32_x}".format(260764824896579434326633182196140447999)
Out[248]: 'c42d_7a7d_155b_93f7_658c_20c9_fea5_98ff'
```

But I can't change that underscore to a colon, I know I can use `str.replace` but still I want it done in one command.

---

Performance comparison:

```
In [253]: %timeit "{0:0>32_x}".format(260764824896579434326633182196140447999).replace('_', ':')
988 ns ± 7.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [254]: %timeit ':'.join([hex(260764824896579434326633182196140447999).replace('0x',"").zfill(32)[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 32, 4)])
4.59 µs ± 493 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [255]: %timeit "{0:0>32_x}".format(260764824896579434326633182196140447999)
810 ns ± 48.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

String interpolation is much faster than string slicing.

Comment: what's wrong with this ':'.join([hex(3402823669209384634633746074317682).replace('0x',"").zfill(32)[i:i+4] for i in range(0, 32, 4)])

Comment: "what is the correct f-string syntax to insert a colon every 4 digits" [There is none.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) You must use more than f-strings for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*But regexes are slow:*

Note that you might harness [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) if you want to lessen required time, consider following example

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(stmt='re.sub("(....)","\\1:",s)',setup='import re;s = "c42d7a7d155b93f7658c20c9fea598ff"') # 2.398639300000468
timeit.timeit(stmt='pat.sub("\\1:",s)',setup='import re;s = "c42d7a7d155b93f7658c20c9fea598ff";pat=re.compile("(....)")') # 1.6385453000002599
```

I use different pattern, as I assume input is always 32 hex digits, replace every 4 characters with them followed by `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it. The format specifier I was looking for is `"{:_x}"`

It formats an integer into its hexadecimal representation, and inserts an underscore every four hex digits. Then it is trivial to use `str.replace` to replace underscores with colons.

But unfortunately it is impossible to insert separators while padding using f-string alone, other tools are required.

But it does the hardest part of representing integer in hexadecimal format and inserting a colon every four digits. The only work left is padding.

`len(s)` is very cheap, and string multiplication is also very cheap.

Using simple arithmetic I got this:

```py
ipv6 = "{:_x}".format(n).replace('_', ':'); l = len(ipv6)              
if l != 39: ipv6 = '0000:' * ((39 - l) // 5) + '0' * (4 - l % 5) + ipv6
```

This:

```
((39 - l) // 5)
```

Calculates how many fields should be inserted to the left.

`39 - l` calculates how many more characters are required to make the string have a length of 39. Then use floor division to calculate the number of fields needed.

This:

```
(4 - l % 5)
```

Calculates how many leading zeros should be inserted into the last field, each field should have 4 digits and with the separator each field will be 5 characters long, `l % 5` calculates the number of digits of the leftmost field, and subtract it from 4 to get the number of leading zeros needed.

It is much faster than string slicing.

---

Actually it can indeed be done with f strings in one line, plus bit shifts and mod operations, it is just more cumbersome and much slower than I had expected:

```py
def format_ipv6(n):
    return f'{(n>>112)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>96)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>80)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>64)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>48)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>32)%65536:0>4x}:{(n>>16)%65536:0>4x}:{(n)%65536:0>4x}'
```

But it indeed does it in one line, I have tried to use it with generator expressions with range and str.join, but doing so slows it down further...